# Best way to call helper class function through ajax in module

Tags: module, jquery, ajax

I need to access helper class function through ajax request.

**In JS file :-**

```
var sbfootscores = {};

    (function($){
        sbfootscores.getTeams = function(competition_id){
            $.ajax({
                url:'',
                type:"POST",
                data:{com_id:competition_id},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    })(jQuery)
```

**In helper Class:-**

```
public static function getTeams(){
        //i need to access this function 
    }
```

What url to put in ajax's options url??

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your module is utilising the **com_ajax** component that is included in Joomla 3.2+ then you can use the following:

```
url: 'index.php?option=com_ajax&module=NAME&method=getTeams&format=json'
```

Have a look at the Ajax Interface documentation for more information:

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

Comment: thank you. It helped but is there any other way to get this done without com_ajax ?

Comment: Yes, but I would not recommend it. com_ajax is there to make your life much easier. If you need to support older versions of Joomla that don't include the *com_ajax* component, then you can always display a warning saying the user must download/install it. There is a standalone version of it that's available to install ;)